# Django: serialize ValuesQuerySet for javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I want to loop over a queryset and access the the field values in javascript.

I'm sending the queryset from the view to the template:

```
render(request, 'home.html', {'data': queryset})
```

Now I want to access some of the fields in javascript. This cannot happen with `data` since it is not yet serialized.

I have no option but to get a serialized version of the queryset with the concerned fields...

```
userData = UserDetails.objects.all().values("first_name", "email")
from django.core import serializers
data2 = serializers.serialize('json', userData)
```

...but I am getting following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I tried the solution given here [Serializing data results from query with select_related into json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994290/serializing-data-results-from-query-with-select-related-into-json) but in the javascript I get the following data:

```
"[{&quot;first_name&quot;: &quot;pream&quot;}, {&quot;first_name&quot;: &quot;micel&quot;}, {&quot;first_name&quot;: &quot;Johhy&quot;}, {&quot;first_name&quot;: &quot;hraper&quot;}]"
```

Any direction to resolve the issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried ```import json``` and ```json.dumps(userData)```?

Comment: yes i did tried but its not encoding properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a solution:

Use the same serialization in the views file, add in the template context and pass it to the template.

```
data2 = serializers.serialize('json', userData)
context = { 
        'data2' : data2,
}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

From your template get this json from the context as below and will be serialized with '"' and not 'quot;'.

The scapejs instruction will do the work

```
var jsonData = "{{ data2|escapejs }}";
```

It worked for me.

Regards