# Django - serializing queryset along with related models

Tags: json, django, serialization

There are hundreds of posts related to an elementary goal.

I have a simple model:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
     # I've got only two fields in reality, 
     # but let's suppose there are 150 of them

class ModelB(models.Model):
    # fields

class ModelC(models.Model):
    field_c = Integer
    modelA = models.ForeignKey('ModelB')
    modelB = models.ForeignKey(ModelC)

model_c_instance = ModelC.objects.select_related().get(pk=pk)
```

All I want to do is to come up with a JSON object which would include the fields for ModelA and ModelB.

1. Wadofstaff ([post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753359/serializing-foreign-key-objects-in-django)) does not suit for Django 1.7 and higher.
2. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994290/serializing-data-results-from-query-with-select-related-into-json) does not shed light on how I should serialize the objects.
3. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032362/django-serializing-queryset-with-related-entity-fields) tell about Full Serializers, but there's no code snippet to see how it is used.

My final JSON object should look like

```
[{
    "model": "userinfo", 
    "fields": {
           "field_c ": "9966", 
           "modelA": [{ 
                  # modelA fields
          }
           etc...
    }]
```

Do I need REST framework ? Or Full Serializers ?
Please could anyone suggest a structured answer to this topic. I can't come up with a solution for two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [nested relationship](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships). You don't show anything about the `userinfo` model so this answer doesn't take that into account. You could do something similar to this pseudo-code:

```
# serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers


class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA       


class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB


class ModelCSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    modelA = ModelASerializer(many=True)
    modelB = ModelBSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelC
```